# I want to ask my failed code

Tags: c

This is a exercise in teach yourself c in 21days.

The question is : Write a function that accepts two strings. Use the `malloc()` function to allocate enough memory to hold the two strings after they have been concatenated. Return a pointer to this new string.

So, I was make First code. but dosen't operate. The function in code is following :

```
 char *concate(char *p, char *q)
 {
    int i, len;
    char *r;

    if((r = (char *)malloc(100)) == NULL){
        printf("Allocate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    r = p;
    for(i = 0; r[i] != '\0'; ++i)
            ;
    len = i;
    for(i = 0; q[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++len)
         r[len] = q[i];

    return r;
}
```

There are no compile error but run-time error.

Because i want only use pointer variable solve this problem.

But i have no idea, use following code solved problem.

```
char *concate(char *p, char *q)
{
    int i, len;
    char *r;

    if((r = (char *)malloc(1000)) == NULL){
        exit(1);
     }

    for (i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        r[i] = p[i];

    len = i;

    for(i = 0; q[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++len)
        r[len] = q[i];

    r[len] = '\0';


    return r;
}
```

This code can run, and can have i wanted result.

My question is, How can i only use pointer variable get result?

I want use `*p, *q, *r` and pointer arithmetic and some variable( i for loop).

I solved problem, but feel not good, because i use array to solved this.

Please help me! thank you.

***I asked that how only use pointer variable can express(solve) question of above.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. in main(), arguments for the function is String.

Comment: You need to study `strlen`, `strcpy`, null termination of strings... study strings in general.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(p) + strlen(q) + 1)`

Comment: My question is so bad? i have -2 vote. But dosen't matter. i already have a goooood answer. Thanks everyone who saw my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are allocating the memory of 100 as a random value, hoping it is enough. It is a better approach to find the length of each string and allocate memory for the combined length.

Secondly, you are overwriting the pointer to the allocated memory by using `r = p;` You need to use `strcpy` to copy the string from `r` to `p`.

Here is a solution using only pointers

```
char *concate(char *p, char *q)
{
    int i, len=0, ;
    char *r, *temp;

    temp = p;
    for(; *temp ; ++temp)
            len++;
    temp = q;        
    for(; *temp ; ++temp)
            len++;

    if((r = malloc(len+1)) == NULL){
        printf("Allocate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (temp = r; *p; p++, temp++)
       *temp = *p;

    for (; *q; q++, temp++)
       *temp = *q;

    *temp = '\0'; 

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! can solve thie problem only use pointer as well!

Comment: Yes. If i studied strcpy function, then don't need write like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the address returned by `malloc` in

```
if((r = (char *)malloc(100)) == NULL){
    printf("Allocate failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
r = p; /* Memory leak */
```

In consequence, you don't have room to store the result, change to

```
strcpy(r, p);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but I'm not study about strcpy yet. (After chapter may study).

Comment: Then, implement your  own `strcpy` with a loop: `while ((*r++ = *p++));`, don't forget to rewind `r` and `p` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be below answer is what you are looking for.

```
char *concate(char *p, char *q)
{
    char *res = p;

    while (*p)
        *p++;

    *p--;

    while (*q)
    {
        *p++;
        *p = *q;
        *q++;
    }
    *++p = *q;

    return res;
}
```

We can optimize it more.
Let me know if I have missed something

Comment: thank yor for answer!

Comment: We need to allocate memory for store a result. I think declare *res and initialize to p then not enough to store result. I go to home test your answer. thank you for help!

Comment: In my opinion no need to allocate the memory for *res (unless we are doing strcpy, just realloc the memory of *p with length of *p and *q)

Comment: You write code is fail on my computer, because that have run-time error. I think, decalre res and that initialize to p is overwriting. and length of res and length of p are equal. so we try to add a string to res then have error.... Can you understand my talk?? T.T...I'm sorry....

Comment: This is what I was trying on my system.

Comment: int main()
{
 char *str1 = (char*)malloc(100);
 char *str2 = (char*)malloc(100);
 strcpy(str1, "these ");
 strcpy(str2, "Strings");

 concate(str1, str2);
 puts(str1);
 return 0;
}

char *concate(char *p, char *q)
{
 char *res = p;

 while (*p)
  *p++;

 *p--;

 while (*q)
 {
  *p++;
  *p = *q;
  *q++;
 }
 *++p = *q;

 return res;
}

Comment: Oh, we are difference is declare and initialize at main(). I just pointer to string constant in main(). Thank you!!

Comment: I still have a run-time error. I will try to find why i can't execute.

Comment: We are must declare str1 and str2  following : char *str1 = (char *) malloc(100), char *str2 = (char *) malloc(100). Because malloc is allocate a requested memory, and that return first address of allocated memory , and the return type is void *.

Comment: Yes, that was copy paste error from Editor. Thanks for highlighting it.